# i have added a dependency : Wallpaper_manager: and run flutter code in terminal with command -> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety then show error

Tags: flutter, wallpapermanager

PS D:\coding\android devlopment\flutter_projects\wallpaper_app> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
C:\Users\amits\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\wallpaper_manager-1.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mulgundkar\wallpaper_manager\WallpaperManagerPlugin.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
String assetLookupKey = FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath);
^
symbol:   method getInstance()
location: class FlutterLoader
C:\Users\amits\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\wallpaper_manager-1.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mulgundkar\wallpaper_manager\WallpaperManagerPlugin.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
String assetLookupKey = FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath);
^
symbol:   method getInstance()
location: class FlutterLoader
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':wallpaper_manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             16.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
PS D:\coding\android devlopment\flutter_projects\wallpaper_app>

i have no ides that what is this error ?? how to solve it ?? please help me